# Sound not working in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, wubi, ubuntu-gnome

Please help me fix audio not working in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. Migrated from Wubi.
It worked before migration from wubi though. IDK why it doesnt work anymore.